# Change default tab width in PowerPoint?

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint

How can I change the default tab spacing, tab width or tab size for all my PowerPoint slides forever?

In PowerPoint 2016 I don't like the default tab spacing of 1". I can go to paragraph ribbon and change it to 0.5" (or whatever), but it only changes it locally. I have also tried changing the tab notches on the ruler, but this also doesn't change things in future text boxes/PowerPoint presentations.

Comment: You need to change the default template to do this. [This may be useful](https://www.indezine.com/products/powerpoint/learn/themes/2013/change-default-template-theme.html)

Answer (score 4):

1. Open the "Paragraph" window (Tab "Home", Section "Paragraph", click small icon on the bottom right).
2. Click the "Tabs..." button (bottom left)
3. Adjust the "Default tab stops" as desired

Answer (score 0):

Choose Tabs from the Format menu. Word displays the Tabs dialog box. (See Figure 1.)
Change the value in the Default Tab Stops control. You can change it in .01-inch increments, from 0.01 inches to 22 inches.
Click on OK.

Comment: Your answer says "See Figure 1", talks about Word not Power Point, and mentions the Format menu without saying how to reach it. More details please.